# Tips for a programmer being good at support system

Tags: software-industry, work-environment, job-change

I've been a java enterprise developer for a long time but now I received a good oportunity to work supporting a large financial system. My routines are mainly log analysis, attending meetings, sending emails and occasionally changing code because the system is already really mature. Most of times bugs are more related to the environment instead of the code itself.
How can I avoid being bored and stay motivated? My boss asked me if I'm interested in the job I said to him sincerely "I'm a developer but its such an oportunity for deepening business knowledge", because in fact it is.

Comment: Guys at Interview the guy didn't asked me about support, about anything related to these tasks. My resume is very clear about my previous experiences, I'm a developer. I'm feeling cheated, because as a developer I should do tasks for developers not for supporting other people systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you **love** programming, changing code and are challenged by and enjoy a fast paced environment. Don't go to the app support route. You will be bored out of your mind and will find ways to **improve** the system. But the paperwork to implement those will drive you crazy. One day you will do it, assuming it has no harm and no one will notice. Which in turn will blow up in your face, taking away your credibility and may cause the termination of your employment.

Short of having done any of this, you will be bored so much that quitting and walking away will look like a better and better option with every passing day.

On the other hand, if you have an ambition to go to the management levels, this position is definitely the right step to stand on the corporate ladder, compared to programming. Be ready to go countless, mind-numbing meetings, create meaningless powerpoint slide decks, while doing minimal technical work, thisp position is right up in your alley.

Comment: This is one valid perspective, but I don't think a service job automatically must be a bad experience.  And if you go into a job with a negative view like this, it can make things much worse.

Comment: Don't get me wrong. I am an EE and my foray into computers was a pure support role, because I knew how to control electrical test equipment with programs I wrote. It was UNIX support jobs and been doing it for the past 25+ years and never regretful. But I have worked with people who were laid off from their development jobs and come to work with me because, my environment is stable and if you don't screw up badly, you have a job no matter what. That is where things go south real fast. They want to have the freedom like they are developers with their hands tied on their backs.

Comment: I would ask my boss a replace I don't want to stay keeping such work. I'm not a support analyst I'm a developer, I worked to be one and I'm not willing to quit development in favour of a job like that.

Comment: Hi @MelBurslan thanks for your answer. It took me a long time to understand someone I used to work with and the reason why he went that path, even if everyone knew he was not at ease in her job. Thanks

Comment: I see that some people are feeling strongly against my views. Please try to understand, this question can not be answered in a clear cut way, like black and white. There are just anecdotal examples. I have written what I have seen in my 25+ years of doing corporate systems support. Your mileage can wildly vary. But as far as comparing development track and support track of IT operations, development is more like tje wild west where support is like IRS going through your tax records, i.e.very structured and to the facts. Just wanted to clear this out

Comment: My problem is not only frustration, my problem is I don't feel myself capable of performing well at such position. The second issue is I'm an outsider in the first year on this country. I don't exactly how things works here.

Comment: If you don't have a serious language barrier, being an outsider doesn't have any role to play here, but if you think you are not capable of discussing matters in meetings because of your limited language skills, than it is a legitimate concern. Because most support roles, as I have said before, will involve a lot of meetings and may be very frequent midnight conference calls because something went horribly bad and everyone is expected to speak up and explain their ow positions.

Answer (score 5):

Some thoughts:

**Do an excellent job**.  This is rewarding almost no matter what the work is.

**Improve the way the support works.** Perhaps the current method of supporting the system could be improved upon?  For example, complaints or problems could be tracked better; manual support tasks could be automated; log files could be automatically monitored for problems; etc.

Redesigning processes can have some of the same rewards as software development.

**Find ways to measure the support quality (if it is not already)**.  For example, perhaps you would want to measure system uptime, number of incidents, time to resolve incidents, and so on.  If measurement is already in place, perhaps it can be improved.

Having a way to measure what you are doing will increase motivation for you.  It will also add value to the system and give you some important information you can report to management.

**Keep an eye out for software development opportunities**.  Ultimately, the above suggestions can make this job more satisfying, but it is still not the same as a software development job for someone who wants to do that.  So, I would try to find a way to transition into more software development.

That could be through some of the suggestions above (it may be logical to do a fair amount of development of systems to help with support).  Or it may be looking for a different role to move into.

Comment: I'm really bored on these tasks, should I ask for a replacement? I'm at a customer for a third party and I think they omit to me at enterview that I would be asigned to such position.I'm not a support guy I'm a developer!

Comment: @lambdapool then look for a new job--externally if there are no internal opportunities to switch to development.

Comment: I was sent here from my real employer its such a body shop company.